# Seeing overview of all application releases across environments in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We're using Azure Devops Pipelines to do all of our deployments. We have 4 environments: Dev, QA, UAT and Production and we have about 3 dozen applications that we're deploying. I want to be able to, at a glance, see what version of each application we have in each environment. So, for instance, if I'm working on a release for 2.0.0, I want to be able to see where 2.0.x has been deployed and whether each deployed version of each application in each environment is the most recent version. Here's a mockup of what this information *could* look like, although I'm not picky on the appearance as long as it's readable.

[image]

Is this something that can be accomplished using tools in Azure Devops?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there isn't a built-in feature that can show application versions in each environment.

Information such as deployment status and environments is relevant to releases/release pipelines, so you can easily get this information by accessing the releases/release pipelines. Azure DevOps also provides some widgets that allow you to easily view the state for each environment, such as [Deployment status](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/widget-catalog?view=azure-devops#deployment-status-widget) and [Release pipeline overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/widget-catalog?view=azure-devops#release-definition-widget).

However, the applications and application versions are not directly related to the releases or release pipelines. If you use REST API to get the release/release pipeline definition, you cannot find them. Therefore, it is difficult to get them outside of the release.

So, if you want to implement this feature, you may need to output the application and application version information during the running of release pipelines.

Comment: Hmmmm, we may be using Azure Pipelines fundamentally incorrectly. We build and deploy from Pipelines, we don't ever use Releases. Is the intended use to be that you use Pipelines to create artifacts and then you use Releases to push those artifacts through different environments? Or are Releases an optional feature that just provide a different experience for managing a release?

Comment: Hello @omatase, release pipeline is optional. It provides visual features that make it easier for users to go through deployment process, deploy to multiple environments, and track releases. It's not required, and it can only use classic UI pipelines. If you are comfortable with yaml, it is recommended that you build and reploy in Pipelins.